# Group data sets in a multidimensional array by a shared subarray value and push accumulated values into a column of the group

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping

I'm using PHP, and I have the following array and have been trying to figure out how I can flatten it in the following manner.  This is an array that is created from a JSON by using json_decode, and the end result will be another json file.

So wherever we have a unique name, the `patternType` and `type` will always be the same in every element of the parent array.  I need a way to basically "collapse" the array and combine the array's while adding new element to the action array.

Current Data Structure.

```
[
    'abc' => [
        [
            'foo' => '*',
            'action' => 'Read',
            'resource' => [
                'name' => 'name_1',
                'patternType' => 'fixed',
                'type' => 'partition',
            ],
        ],
        [
            'foo' => '*',
            'action' => 'Write',
            'resource' => [
                'name' => 'name_1',
                'patternType' => 'fixed',
                'type' => 'partition',
            ],
        ],
        [
            'foo' => '*',
            'action' => 'Read',
            'resource' => [
                'name' => 'name_2',
                'patternType' => 'fixed',
                'type' => 'partition',
            ],
        ],
        [
            'foo' => '*',
            'action' => 'Alter',
            'resource' => [
                'name' => 'name_2',
                'patternType' => 'fixed',
                'type' => 'partition',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Needed Data Structure

```
Array
(
    [abc] => Array
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [foo] => *
                    [action] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Read
                            [1] => Write
                        )
                    [resource] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => name_1
                            [patternType] => fixed
                            [type] => partition
                        )

                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [foo] => *
                    [action] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Read
                            [1] => Alter
                        )
                    [resource] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => name_2
                            [patternType] => fixed
                            [type] => partition
                        )

                )
)
```

I've tried various functions like array_merges, array_merge_recursive, etc...  I also tried looping through the array, and creating a secondary array and creating the data structure properly there, but i always have the problem of figuring out how to reference the parent arrays in that case, b/c the order of the child arrays can always differ.

Answer (score 1):

Mopping up unwanted keys with `array_values()` can be avoided by pushing reference variables in the result array.  This is a more direct approach.

I assume that "resource name" is a reliable means of identifying data set uniqueness.  Declare references variables by this identifier.

If an identifier has not been encountered before, cast the `action` value as a lone-element array, define the reference variable's data, then push in the result array.  If an identifier has been encountered previously, merely push the new `action` value into the reference's `action` subarray.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8KvQI))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $sets) {
    foreach ($sets as $set) {
        $id = $set['resource']['name'];
        if (!isset($ref[$id])) {
            $set['action'] = (array) $set['action'];
            $ref[$id] = $set;
            $result[$key][] = &$ref[$id];
        } else {
            $ref[$id]['action'][] = $set['action'];
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

---

Alternatively, if you'd like to merely mutate the input array without generating a new array, adjust the reference to point to the `action` subarray of the first encountered set of a given `name` value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fIWcH))

```
foreach ($array as $key => &$sets) {
    foreach ($sets as $i => &$set) {
        $id = $set['resource']['name'];
        if (!isset($ref[$id])) {
            $set['action'] = (array) $set['action'];
            $ref[$id] = &$set['action'];
        } else {
            $ref[$id][] = $set['action'];
            unset($array[$key][$i]);
        }
    }
}
var_export($array);
```

Answer (score -2):

here is the solution for you

```
<?php
$array = [
    "abc" => [
        [
                    "foo" => "*",
                    "action" => "Read",
                    "resource" => [
                            "name" => "name_1",
                            "patternType" => "fixed",
                            "type" => "partition"
                        ]

        ],
        [
                    "foo" => "*",
                    "action" => "Write",
                    "resource" => [
                            "name" => "name_1",
                            "patternType" => "fixed",
                            "type" => "partition"
                        ]

        ],
        [
                    "foo" => "*",
                    "action" => "Read",
                    "resource" => [
                            "name" => "name_2",
                            "patternType" => "fixed",
                            "type" => "partition"
                        ]

        ],
         [
                    "foo" => "*",
                    "action" => "Alter",
                    "resource" => [
                            "name" => "name_2",
                            "patternType" => "fixed",
                            "type" => "partition"
                        ]


        ],
    ]
    
];

$grouparr = [];
$tempVal;
$action;



foreach ($array['abc'] as $key => $val) {
   if (isset($tempVal['resource']['name']) && ($val['resource']['name'] == $tempVal['resource']['name'])){
    $grouparr[$key] = $val;
    $actions = [$action];
    array_push($actions, $grouparr[$key]['action']);
    $grouparr[$key]['action'] = $actions;

   } else {
     $action = $val['action'];
     $tempVal = $val;
   }
      
 }

print_r(array_values($grouparr));

?>
```

Comment: We should not see any modern PHP scripts leaning on the stfu operator (`@`).  Also, there is never a good reason to post a code-only answer on Stack Overflow -- every answer should include a plain English explanation with the intent to educate and empower.